# Case insensitive search in Mongo

Tags: regex, mongodb, pattern-matching, match, case-insensitive

I am using a case insensitive search in Mongo, something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/5500823/1028488.

ie. I am using a regex with options i. But I am having trouble restricting the regex to just that word, it performs more like a 'Like' in SQL

eg: if I use query like
`{"SearchWord" : { '$regex' : 'win', $options: '-i' }}`, it shows me results for win, window & winter. How do i restrict it to jsut show win?

I tried `/^win$/` but it's saying invalid JSON... Please suggest away.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use `'$regex':'^win$'` or `/^win$/i` (notice no quote on the second one)

Source here : [Regex in queries with Mongo](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions)

Comment: "^win$" pattern is not so obvious in their document. It's almost like a fine print. So, thanks.

Answer (score 204):

You can Use `$options => i` for case insensitive search. Giving some possible examples required for string match.

Exact case insensitive `string`

```
db.collection.find({name:{'$regex' : '^string$', '$options' : 'i'}})
```

Contains `string`

```
db.collection.find({name:{'$regex' : 'string', '$options' : 'i'}})
```

Start with `string`

```
db.collection.find({name:{'$regex' : '^string', '$options' : 'i'}})
```

End with `string`

```
db.collection.find({name:{'$regex' : 'string$', '$options' : 'i'}})
```

Doesn't Contains `string`

```
db.collection.find({name:{'$regex' : '^((?!string).)*$', '$options' : 'i'}})
```

Keep this as a bookmark, and a reference for any other alterations you may need.
http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Comment: By mistake, you had put the example of "Contains string" inside "Exact case insensitive string" and vice-versa. I have edited your answer by swapping the examples for those two cases and also corrected some grammatical mistakes.

Comment: @gauravparmar: Please check and correct if anything is incorrect.

Comment: I have edited your answer but it has to be peer-reviewed, it says.

Answer (score 24):

**UPDATE**: As of MongoDB 2.4 one would use a "text" index and full text search query to do this. You can read about them [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/). If using a recent MongoDB the approach below would be silly and unecessary.

However, if you have MongoDB < 2.4.0 you could use a regular expression like so:

```
> db.reg.insert({searchword: "win"})
> db.reg.insert({searchword: "window"})
> db.reg.insert({searchword: "Win"})

> db.reg.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ecd2e33dd68c9021e453d12"), "searchword" : "win" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ecd2e36dd68c9021e453d13"), "searchword" : "window" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ecd2e39dd68c9021e453d14"), "searchword" : "Win" }

> db.reg.find({ searchword: /^win$/i })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ecd2e33dd68c9021e453d12"), "searchword" : "win" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ecd2e39dd68c9021e453d14"), "searchword" : "Win" }
```

However, your version wasn't working because you don't need the "/"s when using the $regex operator:

```
> db.reg.find({ searchword: { $regex: "^win$", $options: '-i' }})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ecd2e33dd68c9021e453d12"), "searchword" : "win" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ecd2e39dd68c9021e453d14"), "searchword" : "Win" }
```

Please note that case insensitive queries do not use the index so it might make sense to make a lowercase searchword field so that you can speed that query up.

Go [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions) for more info on RegularExpressions

Comment: $text isn't a replacement for regex. It is pretty restrictive and wouldn't allow him to find "winter" with a search for "win".

Comment: @BT You're right. In order to do that one would have to store n-grams and match on those. [Fuzzy search with MongoDB and Python](https://medium.com/xeneta/fuzzy-search-with-mongodb-and-python-57103928ee5d#.yg7f3428b)

Comment: Also: [Case Insensitive Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-case-insensitive/)

Answer (score 1):

```
{
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["$_id", "$$itemId"] },
                {
                  $regexMatch: {
                    input: "$brandData.name",
                    regex: "sample",
                    options: "i",
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
```

Answer (score -1):

For Case insensitive

```
db.users.find({"name":{ $regex : new RegExp("Vi", "i") }})
```

For Case sensitive

```
db.users.find({"name":"Vi"})
// or
db.users.find({"email":"example@mail.com"})
```

search in user table

name is column name and "Vi" text that are searched

Answer (score -1):

Use $strcasecmp. The aggregation framework was introduced in MongoDB 2.2. You can use the string operator "$strcasecmp" to make a case-insensitive comparison between strings. It's more recommended and easier than using regex.

Here's the official document on the aggregation command operator: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strcasecmp/#exp._S_strcasecmp .