# Case insensitivity when searching MongoDB - is eval() ok?

Tags: javascript, security, mongodb, eval

I have lots of records stored in MongoDB, and they're (mostly) written in title-case. Sample prototype:

```
{
   'name':'Awesome Pair of Jeans',
   'designer':'Company123',
   'description':'This pair of jeans is really great. Navy colour.'
},{
   'name':'awesome jeans part 2',
   'designer':'company123',
   'description':'This pair of jeans is also navy in colour.'
}
```

In my frontend (built on Angular/Node), I want to give the user the ability to search for records, but as MongoDB's search is case-sensitive I'm having some issues.

Currently, if someone searches for the word "awesome" (lowercase) in the "name" field, the only way I've been able to ensure both `awesome` and `Awesome` is returned is to query as follows:

**First, the query is wrapped in a regex. So if the user searches for "awesome", it's passed to the query as `name:/awesome/i`**

```
exports.postsQuery = function(req,res){
    var query = req.params.query; // 'name:/awesome/i'
    var properties = query.split('+');
    var criteria = {};
    properties.forEach(function(property) {
        var propParts = property.split('=');
        criteria[propParts[0]] = eval(propParts[1]); // criteria{name:/awesome/i};
    });

    db.products.find(criteria, function (err, record) {
       // Do stuff
    });
}
```

This returns the correct results, but I'm wondering how secure it is, and if there's a better way to do this.

Similar to this question: [Case insensitive search in Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246019/case-insensitive-search-in-mongo) but I'm wondering what is best practices for speed and security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of building the `/awesome/i` string, its probably better to pass down `awesome` and then instead of

`criteria[propParts[0]] = eval(propParts[1])`

you can do

`criteria[propParts[0]] = new RegExp(propParts[1], "i");`

which will return the same `RegExp` you are currently getting but without using `eval` and using less string manipulation.