# Trying to find a value like mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Hi I am trying to find a value that is like a variable in a mongodb database.
I get no results though and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. If my username is just d then I should see some users with d in their name but I don't.

```
//Find a user
router.get('/findUser/:username', function (req, res) {
  var user = req.params.username;
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('userlist');
  collection.find({'username':  '/^' + user + '/' }, {}, function (e, docs) {
    res.json(docs);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caret sign  `^` means: beginning of the text. If you get rid of that, you have a proper "contains" query if that is what you expect.

Also, you might want to add an 'i' after the second slash in order to make the query case-insensitive:

Mind you, I don't think that the `'/'` based syntax works in conjunction with a variable (`user` in your case). So try this one instead:

```
collection.find({'username':{'$regex' : user, '$options' : 'i'}})
```

Be sure to check out this SO answer, too:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33971033/6440033

Comment: Thanks, yes that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

With `/^d/` (no quotes) you can create a RegExp in JavaScript. In your example you used quotes and hence created a plain string instead of a RegExp. If you want to use a variable in your regular expression, you have to use the `RegExp` constructor:

```
var userRegex = new RegExp('^' + user);
collection.find({'username':  userRegex}, function (e, docs) {
    res.json(docs);
  });
```

Also see [mongo js docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html)

Comment: As @dnickless pointed out, you can also just leave out the caret, if you want a "contains". If you need a case-insensitive search, add the  `i` flag: `new RegExp(user, 'i');`

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it seems to work:

```
router.get('/findUser/:username', function (req, res) {


var user = req.params.username;
var reg = new RegExp(user, 'i')
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('userlist');
collection.find({ 'username': { $regex: reg }}, function (e, docs) {
res.json(docs);
});
```

});

Comment: You don't need to do both. Either use the $regex syntax with the options parameter or create the regular expression and use it like `{'username': reg}`. See the link to the docs I posted under "Regular expressions in queries"