# Get data without case sensitive from mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

How to get data without case sensitive from mongo:

```
searchRequest
   {  asset: '121',
      certificateNumber: '',
      currentDate: '',
      customerPO: '213',
      Area: 'usa',
      serial: '' 
    }
```

Get records if I enters Area in USA or usa

Code for Search

```
certificate.find(data).then(function(result) {
    if (!_.isEmpty(result)) {
        successData(RESPONSE.sendResponse(true, true, result, MESSAGE.SUCCESS, STATUS_CODE.OK));
    } else {
        successData(RESPONSE.sendResponse(true, false, null, MESSAGE.DATA_NOT_AVAILABLE, STATUS_CODE.OK));
    }
})
```

Comment: data = { Area: /usa/i } more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query

Comment: cant pass direct usa. its getting though csv read

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case insensitive search in Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246019/case-insensitive-search-in-mongo)