# How do I search for queries without case sensitivity in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How would I search for queries in MongoDB (using the mongoose library) without them being case sensitive?

Lets say I have a query that has the string data of `Adam`. That query is case sensitive, so searching for that query as `adam` will return a null.

I tried using regex, and disabling the case sensitivity with it. It did the job, but now whenever I search for `ad` it finds & returns `Adam`, which is something that I don't want.

How would I search for case insensitive queries the right way?
Thank you!

**Here's my code for finding queries without case sensitivity, but with the regex bug.**

```
server.get('/test/:username', (req, res)=> {
    const username = req.params.username

    usersDB.findOne({'username': {'$regex': username, $options: '?-i'}}, (err, data)=> {
        if(err) {
            throw err
        } 

        if(!data) {
            console.log('user not found')
            res.redirect('/')
        } else if(data) {
            console.log('user found: ' + data.username)
            res.redirect('/')
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Case insensitive search in Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246019/case-insensitive-search-in-mongo)

Comment: Hey @sidgate! I really appreciate you sending that, unfortunatly, no. I tried all of those responses and instead of fixing the search bug, it just returns a null.

Comment: you need to use the right regex `'^string$'` , to mark start and end of the string. alternatively use `$toLower` and match the  lowercase string.

Comment: Sorry man, I don't really understand what you're trying to say.
Are you telling me to make it ``usersDB.findOne({'username': {'$regex': '^string$', $options: 'i'}}`` or ``usersDB.findOne({'username': {'$regex': '^username$', $options: 'i'}}``

because neither works. Thank you so much for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `$options` property to `i` value, and not `?-i`:

```
{'username': {'$regex': `^${username}$`, $options: 'i'}}
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/wq0hfAnodmL

Comment: Nope, it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Try to console.log(req.params.username) to see if you got valid value. I added working example in my answer.

Comment: Yep, the console logs the right value. 
``ada`` still outputs ``Adam`` & the console log outputs ``ada``

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that you don't want partial match. I updated my answer again. Can you try it now?