# Text search with symbols in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am looking for a string in mongo that does not discriminate between lower and upper case, the problem is that if a record has a "+" sign it does not find it.

```
{ username: { $regex: "ExamPle+33@gmail.com", $options: "i" } } // does not work


{ username: { $regex: "ExamPle33@gmail.com", $options: "i" } } // works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must escape the character "+".

Try something like this:

```
variable = "^ExamPle\\+33@gmail.com$"
db.testcollection.find({ username: { $regex: variable, $options: "i" } })
```

Look at the following link [Case insensitive search in Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246019/case-insensitive-search-in-mongo)