# Mongodb how to search by regex OR on many fields?

Tags: mongodb, go

I want to make a search on many fields of mongodb.

Here is what I did so far

```
var filter bson.D
filter = append(filter, bson.E{"title", primitive.Regex{Pattern: "input", Options: "i"}})
filter = append(filter, bson.E{"author", primitive.Regex{Pattern: "input", Options: "i"}})
filter = append(filter, bson.E{"content", primitive.Regex{Pattern: "input", Options: "i"}})
cur, err := p.postProposalCollection.Find(ctx, filter)
```

However it workds as `AND` like this

```
WHERE title ~ 'input' AND author ~ 'input' AND content ~ 'input'
```

I want it to work as OR like this

```
WHERE title ~ 'input' OR author ~ 'input' OR content ~ 'input'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can use `$or` and `$regex` directly

```golang
filter := bson.M{
    "$or": bson.A{
        bson.M{"title": bson.M{"$regex": "input"}},
        bson.M{"author": bson.M{"$regex": "input"}},
        bson.M{"content": bson.M{"$regex": "input"}},
    },
}

p.postProposalCollection.Find(ctx, filter)
```

Comment: how to avoid case sensitive here ?

Comment: add `'$options' : 'i'` to cond like `bson.M{"title": bson.M{"$regex": "input", "$options": "i"}}`

for more, you can check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246019/case-insensitive-search-in-mongo