# Case insensitive query on Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

Could you tell me how can I do case insensitive query on Firestore?

**e.g.**  `Hallway` and `hallway` both must be the same. But below query does exact search. i.e. If db has `Hallway` and I tried to search `hallway` then it shows `no records`.

```
  getSpecificTempBudgetGroup(name: string): AngularFirestoreCollection<BudgetGroup> {
    return this.fireStore.collection<BudgetGroup>(`members/${this.authenticationProvider.member.id}/budgetGroups`, ref => ref
      .where('name', '==', name)
    );
  }
```

I have tried with `toLowerCase()` too. But no luck :( Any clue?

```
getSpecificTempBudgetGroup(name: string): AngularFirestoreCollection<BudgetGroup> {
        return this.fireStore.collection<BudgetGroup>(`members/${this.authenticationProvider.member.id}/budgetGroups`, ref => ref
          .where('name.toLowerCase()', '==', name.toLowerCase())
        );
      }
```

**Note:** I saw the possible duplicate answer too. But it didn't give that much of idea to my use case. But I got useful info using MongoDB answer which I have mentioned below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a property on db like so `lowerCaseName` and after that changed my query as shown below. I have inspired about this solution by [**this MongoDB answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5500823/1077309).

```
  getSpecificTempBudgetGroup(name: string): AngularFirestoreCollection<BudgetGroup> {
    return this.fireStore.collection<BudgetGroup>(`members/${this.authenticationProvider.member.id}/budgetGroups`, ref => ref
      .where('lowerCaseName', '==', name.toLowerCase())
    );
  }
```